# How can I elegantly invert a Map's keys and values?

Tags: haskell

I have a Map (or associative list) that looks like this:

```
[("A", ["KB", "KC"]), ("B", ["KD", "KE"])]
```

How can I concisely transform the above Map so that the keys are the values and the values are the keys, so that the result should look like this?

```
[("KB", "A"), ("KC", "A"), ("KD", "B"), ("KE", "B")]
```

EDIT

Here is my solution

```
invertAList xs = [(val,key) |  (key, vals) <- xs, val <- vals]
```

Comment: `invertAList = concatMap $ uncurry $ liftA2 (flip (,)) . pure`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the key problems here is how to handle the case where a value appears more than once in the "right hand side" assignments:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- "KB" occurs twice.
example = Map.fromList [("A", ["KB", "KC"]), ("B", ["KD", "KB"])]
```

The solution is to use [`Map.fromListWith`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:fromListWith):

```
invert :: Ord v => Map k [v] -> Map v [k]
invert m = Map.fromListWith (++) pairs
    where pairs = [(v, [k]) | (k, vs) <- Map.toList m, v <- vs]

{-
>>> invert (Map.fromList [("A", ["KB", "KC"]), ("B", ["KD", "KE"])])
fromList [("KB",["A"]),("KC",["A"]),("KD",["B"]),("KE",["B"])]

>>> invert (Map.fromList [("A", ["KB", "KC"]), ("B", ["KD", "KB"])])
fromList [("KB",["B","A"]),("KC",["A"]),("KD",["B"])]
-}
```

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
Prelude> let xs = [("A", ["KB", "KC"]), ("B", ["KD", "KE"])]
Prelude> concatMap (\(k, vs) -> [(v, k) | v <- vs]) xs
[("KB","A"),("KC","A"),("KD","B"),("KE","B")]
```

Comment: If you're going for the list comprehension syntax, why not go all out?  `[(v, k) | (k, vs) <- xs, v <- vs]`

Comment: @LouisWasserman No particular reason, I just thought about the function to apply to each element and then stuck `concatMap` in front of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import qualified Data.Map   as M
import           Data.Tuple

swapMap :: M.Map String [String] -> M.Map String String
swapMap = M.fromList . concatMap swapper . M.toList
  where swapper (x, [y,z]) = [(y,x),(z,x)]

*Main> swapMap $ M.fromList [("A", ["KB", "KC"]), ("B", ["KD", "KE"])]
fromList [("KB","A"),("KC","A"),("KD","B"),("KE","B")]
```

Comment: I'd go with `swapper (key, vals) = [(val, key) | val <- vals]`, because otherwise this will only work when there are exactly two items in each list...

Comment: I think we hit on basically the same solution, right?

Comment: @dan, if you only need two elements they will both work. Otherwise yours is better for an arbitrary amount of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Inverting a `Map` can also be done with a fold.

```
import Data.Set as Set
import Data.Map as Map

invert :: (Ord k, Ord v) => Map k v -> Map v (Set k)
invert = foldlWithKey (\acc k v -> insertWith (Set.union) v (Set.singleton k) acc) Map.empty
```

Also, if the original `Map` is a bijection then all the new values should be singletons, or we can write a separate function and leave `Set` out of the type.

```
invertBijection :: (Ord k, Ord v) => Map k v -> Map v k
invertBijection = foldrWithKey (flip Map.insert) Map.empty
```

By the way, this is the same approach as reversing a list with a fold

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

To make the inversion work the way you specified (with the added condition that it flattens the keys) you could write a function. Here is one example of such a function (this could be made slightly more generic but it suits our purposes just fine for now):

```
import Data.Foldable as Foldable

flattenKeys :: (Ord k, Ord v, Foldable t) => Map (t k) v -> Map k (Set v)
flattenKeys = foldlWithKey (\acc keys v -> Map.unionsWith Set.union (acc : fmap (`Map.singleton` Set.singleton v) (Foldable.toList keys))) Map.empty
```

This way if your key is a list, it will add each element of the list as a key.

```
*Main> flattenKeys (Map.fromList [([1,2], "a"), ([2,3], "b")])
fromList [(1,fromList ["a"]),(2,fromList ["a","b"]),(3,fromList ["b"])]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this logical solution

```
swapMap :: (Ord v) => Map k v -> Map v k
swapMap = fromList . map swap . toList
```

- Convert the map to list of tuples
- Swap tuples
- Assemble list back to the map

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this function:

```hs
invertWith :: Ord b => (a -> a -> a) -> Map a b -> Map b a
invertWith combine = M.foldrWithKey (flip $ M.insertWith combine) M.empty
```

It could be used as `invertWith const` (replaces duplicate keys) or `invertWith (error "duplicate key")` (partial function) or with another user-supplied combination function.

The `invertWith` functions feels very natural in the context of the many other `*With` functions in `Data.Map`, to the point where I am wondering why it is not included in the `containers` package to begin with.